# PyCharm: how to add multiple arguments after manage.py: Edit: Don't use quotes

Tags: python, django, pycharm, arguments

**Edit**
Abdul, thanks your comment is the solution: **don't use quotes**.

**Original**
Running tests for my django app I use

```
./manage.py test --settings=soardataDJ.settings.testing
```

which runs fine in a terminal window.

When I try to run/debug it in PyCharm with a run configuration, it fails if I add anything after "test" in the script parameters, as I did in the screenshot below.  It gives the error

```
Unknown command: 'test --settings=soardataDJ.settings.testing'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

But it's not an issue with manage.py, because it works in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Try removing those quotes you have around your parameters. When you add quotes around parameters it usually means that the entire quoted value is one parameter.